# Forest plot from logistf

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, logistic-regression, logistf

I have run a few models in for the penalized logistic model in R using the
logistf package. I however wish to plot some forest plots for the data.

The sjPlot package : http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/custplot/

gives excellent function for the glm output, but no function for the logistf function.

Any assistance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `logistf` objects differ in their structure compared to `glm` objects, but not too much. I've added support for logistf-fitted models, however, 1) model summaries can't be printed and b) predicted probability plots are currently not supported with logistf-models.

I'll update [the code on GitHub](https://github.com/sjPlot/devel) tonight, so you can try the updated `sjp.glm` function...

```
library(sjPlot)
library(logistf)
data(sex2)
fit<-logistf(case ~ age+oc+vic+vicl+vis+dia, data=sex2)
# for this example, axisLimits need to be specified manually
sjp.glm(fit, axisLimits = c(0.05, 25), transformTicks = T)
```

[image]

Comment: btw, you have to set axis limits from 0.001 to 4000 to plot all CI, I just realized... `sjp.glm(fit, axisLimits = c(0.001, 4000), transformTicks = T)` plots all odds ratios and confidence intervals for the above example.